Javascript: How to compare a parent array of array with more than two similar elements of another array and return unique array of arrays


const array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1,3,4], [1,2,5]];
let b = []
let c = [2,3]

  array1.forEach(e => {
    c.some(r => {
     if(e.includes(r))
    b.push(e)
  })
})

console.log(b)



got the result as [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 3, 5 ] ]
but the expected result is [ [ 1, 2, 3 ]]

how to ask a good question

Filter the original array, and use Array.every() and Array.includes() to check that all items in c appear in the subArray:


const array1 = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,2,5]];
const c = [2,3]

const result = array1.filter(subArray => 
  c.every(n => subArray.includes(n))
)

console.log(result)



You can also use the new Set methods to check if c is a subset of subArray:


const array1 = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,2,5]];
const c = new Set([2,3])

const result = array1.filter(subArray => 
  c.isSubsetOf(new Set(subArray))
)

console.log(result)




This code works fine but if we have a [[1, 2, 3], [1,3,4], [1,2,5]], it does return 2 arrays,
I have edited the array of array in the question, please check

No it doesn't. I've updated the examples.

It worked thank you

You're welcome :)
